# API for IPROUTE2 in any programming language

Tags: linux-kernel, iproute, api

Is there any API that can be used to manipulate Linux routing table? I want to write a program that listens to sockets and then modifies routing table accordingly, just a simple code, but need an API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Netlink`. From the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink),

> Netlink was designed for and is used to transfer miscellaneous
>   networking information between the Linux kernel space and user space
>   processes. Networking utilities such as iproute2 use Netlink to
>   communicate with the Linux kernel from user space. Netlink consists of
>   a standard socket-based interface for user space processes and an
>   internal kernel API for kernel modules. It is designed to be a more
>   flexible successor to ioctl. Originally, Netlink used the AF_NETLINK
>   socket family.

My personal preference would be bash scripts for such tasks since I can specify the `iptables` rules/routing in my script itself. If you are using programming language like C, you can probably invoke `system` and then use the return value in your program to do something.

There is one API named **haxwithaxe** available from [here](https://github.com/haxwithaxe/iproute2-API)

Comment: **haxwithaxe** is incomplete, many files/functions are just empty. Seems project was just started but not completed.

Comment: netlink sockets seem to provide the solution, thanks